# anomaly occurs in splashscreen editing code in vb

Tags: vb.net

what are the steps involved when removing a splashscreen from your vb code???

i deleated my splashscreen and then added a new one but my code is still looking for old one?
getting unable to create a manifest resorce name for"My Project\SplashScreen2.resx".

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms project targeting .NET Framework? If not, how EXACTLY is this splash screen being used? If so, you probably still have the old form selected as the splash screen in the project properties. If you were going to delete that form from the project, you should have deselected it there first. You should hopefully still be able to select the new form in the appropriate drop-down. Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem in the question. That includes type of project and target framework. Also provide all relevant tags.